# The overfitting in convolutional neural network

Tags: tensorflow

In linear regression, if the number of predictors is more than the rows of data and we force a regression, the `X'X` will be singular and the coefficients cannot be estimated.

Now I have 50 `good` pics and 20 `bad` pics to do classification and I consider using convolutional neural network.

To my understanding, there will be way more weights/coefficients to be determined in CNN. But I only have 50/20 pics.

Is CNN still applicable with this small sample size? Or will there be a serious over-fitting problem?

Is there a way to see the learning curve to determine the best complexity similar to what we do in classic ML using cross-validation?

Comment: If you only have 70 images on which to train, I don't think you'll be able to use CNNs. Most successful uses have at least 10,000+ images. You can use Tensorboard to output loss for your training/validation sets in order to generate learning curves.

Comment: @JoshVarty Is the 10,000+ the original sample size or the augmented sample size?

Comment: Original. MNIST, ImageNet, SVHN all have 10,000+ original images.

Comment: You may be able to use Transfer Learning and part of a pre-trained network on your images, though: http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/